# WCF 4 REST Template and base64 strings - HTTP 400

Tags: wcf, base64, http-status-code-400

I am trying to submit a long (approx. 155000 characters) base64 string to a WCF REST service using the wcf 4 REST template made available by Microsoft.  Whenever I try submitting the the the XML through the post method either from the client application or fiddler I get a HTTP status code 400 in response to my request.  I have the appropriate web.config settings, pieced together from various blog posts and other stackoverflow posts.

```
   <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  openTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
                 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                 maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

what am I missing here?  Everything else works great; I submit requests that are text/xml format to the service and everything else returns 200, as long as I'm not working with the base64 string.  I know there are a million other posts about wcf message size, but I would appreciate it somebody would take a quick look at mine.

Here is a [link](http://maps.lenexa.com/sampleRequest.rtf) to the sample request I am trying to get the wcf service to handle.

I would appreciate any thoughts anybody might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling tracing at the server side to see what is causing the server to reject the request. Also, double check that:

- The `<endpoint>` element for your service has a `bindingConfiguration` attribute with value "httpBinding"
- The `<service>` element for your service a `name` attribute which matches the **fully-qualified name** of the service class (i.e., with the namespace, essentially the same value you use in the .svc file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I am using routes to manage the requests coming in to the service, no .svc files. I will enable tracing and see what I come up with.

Comment: I enabled the tracing, and it is saying:"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded."  To me, this means that it's not picking up the edits to the maximummessagesize that I feed it it in web.config.  What should the web.config look like for the wcf 4 rest template?

Comment: If you're using the routes, then you're using the default binding created by the WebServiceHostFactory (I assume, since you're using routes and REST). Do change the settings for the default binding, you can simply *remove* the name attribute from the web.config: <webHttpBinding> <binding name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"... />

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it.  I am going to make a new post with the entire web.config I'm using in it to see if anybody has any ideas.